# Add a new entry in a column SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem with SQL which I'm new to.

I created this view:

```
CREATE VIEW country_customer 
AS
    SELECT 
        country,
        COUNT(customer_id) total_customers
    FROM 
        customer
    GROUP BY 
        1
    ORDER BY 
        2 DESC;
```

And as output I got this table:

[image: output]

My question is how can I group all the countries that have 1 customer under the value 'Other'. The value has to appear under the country column at the end.

The result I'm looking for should be the column country with all the countries that has > 1 customer and at the end Other with the sum of all the customers of the country with just 1.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't make sense in a view.

Comment: @TheImpaler, sometimes it actually does, depending on the dbms used.

Comment: @jarlh Can you elaborate?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @TheImpaler, if you select from the view, the result by default comes as the view's ORDER BY specifies.

Comment: @jarlh You are right (just tested it in PostgreSQL). I'm not sure I like the idea, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the database, so chose PostgreSQL for this example.

You can post-process the result set in an external query, as in:

```
create view country_customer as
select country, sum(total_customers) as total_customers
from (
  select
    case when total_customers > 1 then country else 'Other' end as country,
    total_customers
  from (
    SELECT
      country,
      COUNT(customer_id) as total_customers
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY 1
  ) x
) y
GROUP BY 1;
```

Then, the query can run as:

```
select * from country_customer order by total_customers desc;
```

Result:

```
country  total_customers 
-------- --------------- 
France   3               
Other    2               
Nigeria  2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktbrzrhM47REnKxakQtbJ9/0).

Notice that I removed the `ORDER BY` clause. @jarth clarifies that the `ORDER BY` clause can be used in the view; however, I prefer to exclude it from it and apply it on the main query, since in SQL result sets are typically considered *unordered* bags of rows.

Answer (score 0):

(I hope this is what you wanted)
With the view already created use this query to get what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM country_customer where total_customers > 1
UNION
SELECT 'others' as country, sum(total_customers) as country_customer FROM test.clients where total_customers = 1 ORDER BY total_customers desc
```

and here's the result:

[image]